# Do not a knot splines force continuity at each knot?

Tags: spline

Given a cubic spline equation $S(x) = S_0(x), S_1(x), S_2(x)$

Does it follow the continuity rules where $S_0(x_2) = S_1(x_2)$ and $S_1(x_3) = S_2(x_3)$ assuming x1 is the starting point and $x_4$ is the end point?

Comment: The not-a-knot condition just imposes the condition that the supposedly two separate cubics that form the first two pieces (or last two as the case may be) of your spline are in fact the same.